# How to use AND and OR statement inside the component while comparing in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm unable to find proper syntax of the use of AND and OR using inside the component fragments.
Lets say i have data which may return condition in strings

```
conditionOne
conditionTwo
conditionThree
```

I can use if statment like this

```
<React.Fragment>
  {data.condition === 'conditionOne' ? <>Do This </> : <> Do Something Else </>} 
<React.Fragment/>
```

But I want to find out the similar syntax to find, if all conditions meets Or one of the condition meets than `Do Something Else`  or `Do This` .

Comment: Sorry please may you explain what you mean? Are you aware of the logical comparisons like [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) and [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)?

Comment: Yes I tried && but not familiar with ||

Comment: You can simply write a function in the component that returns what you want, when you want it. Then call that function inside the react fragment.

Comment: Problem is this data coming from a mapped array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
['conditionOne', 'conditionTwo', 'conditionThree'].includes(data.condition)
```

this would replace the `data.condition === 'conditionOne'` expression.

You can also store that array somewhere else or use a `Set`.

A less maintainable approach would be to use the logical operators, but that can cause noise in the conditional ternary operation.